# Apache Cordova no reconoce evento click en una imagen

Tags: javascript, html5, cordova

Me encuentro desarrollando con cordova una galeria de imagenes, accedo al directorio contenedor leo su contenido y muestro las imagenes en un section, generado con javascript, de esta forma

```
function success(entries) {
        var i;
        for (i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
            //alert(entries[i].name);
            var rute = entries[i].nativeURL;            
            document.getElementById("photosContent").innerHTML +=  "<div class='photos' ><img src='"+rute+"' class='rounded test'></div>"
        }       
    }
```

Obtengo el src(por que ahi tengo la ruta para poder usarla con el plugin open) al dar click en un elemento de class test, de esta manera

```
$(".test").click(function() {
          let tDIVP = $(this).attr('src');        
          //console.log(tDIVP);
          console.log(tDIVP);
          cordova.plugins.disusered.open(tDIVP, successLP, errorLP);     
        });
```

Utilizo el console para saber si esta recibiendo el evento, pero no lo reconoce, no realiza la accion al clickear.

No manda ningún error, en ocasiones acepta el click, por lo que no hay error en cuanto a sintaxis o logica, solo no reconoce el evento siempre.

Alguna solución.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es la forma en que capturas el evento `$(".test").click(function() {//CODE})`, esta forma se utiliza para elementos que ya existen el la pagina (fueron cargados inicialmente), cuando capturas eventos de elementos que creas despues (cuando la pagina ya esta cargada) tenes que usar `$('body').on('click','.test',function(){//CODE})`

Tu codigo quedaria de la forma siguiente:

```
$('body').on('click','.test',function(){
    let tDIVP = $(this).attr('src');        
    //console.log(tDIVP);
    console.log(tDIVP);
    cordova.plugins.disusered.open(tDIVP, successLP, errorLP);
})
```